# Can't Open Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

Getting the following code opening in the console in 9 separate screens when I try to open Python IDLE. As far as I'm aware, there isn't anything that I have done to the original install. Any ideas? Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no luck. The code shown when I open the program is...

```
try:
    import idlelib.PyShell
except ImportError:
    # IDLE is not installed, but maybe PyShell is on sys.path:
    try:
        from . import PyShell
    except ImportError:
        raise
    else:
        import os
        idledir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(PyShell.__file__))
        if idledir != os.getcwd():
            # We're not in the IDLE directory, help the subprocess find run.py
            pypath = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', '')
            if pypath:
                os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = pypath + ':' + idledir
            else:
                os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = idledir
        PyShell.main()
else:
    idlelib.PyShell.main()
```

I only have the option to close this window and not to create a new Python file.

Comment: _"Getting the following message..."_ Sorry, what message? I just see a code block here.

Comment: Sorry, formatting mess and possible poor sytax on my part. What I mean is this is the code that it's opening up when I try to run IDLE

Comment: The formatting was all over and so I've put it as a code snippet although this probably isn't what I was supposed to do as it's put it in as Javascript. Anyway, you get the idea

Comment: What is this script? What OS and version are you running?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion due to my clarity. When I attempt to open IDLE from Python 3.4 install on Windows 8.1 I get that code pop up with 8 other blank white windows instead of IDLE editor

Comment: So what operating system are you using?

Comment: How did you install Python? How exactly are you trying to run it?

Comment: Installed it from the MSI installer. I'm just running it from the IDLE shortcut on the start menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an Idle maintainer and it is very unclear how you tried to open Idle, what you mean by '9 screens', and what you 're-installed', and on what system and version of Python.

The easiest way to start Idle with installed Python is to use the Start menu icon (on Windows) or the equivalent on other systems.  On a command line, use `python -m idlelib`, where `python` starts some version of installed 3.x.  For uninstalled 3.x or 2.x, use `idlelib.idle`.  From within Python, `import idlelib.idle` starts Idle.

If you have python 2.7 or 3.4 properly installed and running, so that `python -m test.regrtest` runs and passes (`.regrtest` is only needed for 2.x), I would be very surprised if Idle did not run with the methods above.

The code you posted is idlelib/idle.pyw.  It is used by idlelib/idle.bat and may have other specialized uses, such as running Idle with a subprocess call.  I suspect that it is partially obsolete.  In any case, I doubt it will be helpful to you.